# Error compilando programa en C++

Tags: c++, array, variables

Este es mi programa. Estoy usando CodeBlocks. Los errores que me muestra son los siguientes:

- 26 - expected primary-expresion before 'int'.
- 26 - expected ']' before 'int'.
- 26 - expected ')' before 'int'.
- 26 - expected initializer before 'int'.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cmath>

    class Network
    {
        public:
            int ip[4],mask,cont,nhost,nred,pot;
    };

    void head()
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tSubnetting Console" << std::endl;
    };

    int cant(int a)
    {
        head();
        std::cout << "Cuantas redes hay?\n" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a;
        system("cls");
        return a;
    };

    void proc1(Network net[],int n)
    {
        head();
        std::cout << "Cuantos host tiene cada red\n" << std::endl;

        for(int b=0; b<n;b++)
        {
            std::cout<<"R"<<b+1<<": ";
            std::cin>>net[b].nhost;
            std::cout << "nhost-Listo" << std::endl;
            net[b].nred=b+1;
            std::cout << "nred-Listo" << std::endl;
            net[b].pot=1;
            std::cout << "pot-Listo" << std::endl;
            net[b].cont=0;
            std::cout << "cont-Listo" << std::endl;
            while((net[b].pot-2)<net[b].nhost)
            {
                net[b].pot*=2;
                net[b].cont++;
            }
            net[b].mask=32-net[b].cont;
            std::cout << "mask-Listo" << std::endl;
        }
        system("cls");
    };

    void SetIP(Network net[],int n)
    {
        int bmask, bip[4];
        long int num=0;
        for(int z=0;z<n;z++){num+=net[z].pot;}

        if(num<65536){bmask=16; bip[0]=192;bip[1]=168;bip[2]=0;bip[3]=0;}       //Si la red nesecita menos de 65,536 hosts se usa 192.168.0.0/16
        else if(num<1048576){bmask=12; bip[0]=172;bip[1]=16;bip[2]=0;bip[3]=0;} //Si la red nesecita menos de 1,048,576 hosts se usa 172.16.0.0/12
        else{bmask=8; bip[0]=10;bip[1]=0;bip[2]=0;bip[3]=0;}                        // En cualquier otro caso se usa el ip 10.0.0.0/8

        if(bmask==16)
        {
            for(int a=17;a<32;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
                {
                    if(net[b].mask==a)
                    {
                        net[a].ip[0]=bip[0];
                        net[a].ip[1]=bip[1];
                        net[a].ip[2]=bip[2];
                        net[a].ip[3]=bip[3];
                        if((32-a)>=8)
                        {
                            bip[2]+=pow(2,((32-a)-8));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bip[3]+=pow(2,(32-a));
                        }

                        if(bip[3]>255)
                        {
                            bip[2]+=1;
                            bip[3]-=256;
                        }
                        if(bip[2]>255)
                        {
                            bip[1]+=1;
                            bip[2]-=256;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(bmask==12)
        {
            for(int a=13;a<32;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
                {
                    if(net[b].mask==a)
                    {
                        net[a].ip[0]=bip[0];
                        net[a].ip[1]=bip[1];
                        net[a].ip[2]=bip[2];
                        net[a].ip[3]=bip[3];
                        if((32-a)>=16)
                        {
                            bip[1]+=pow(2,((32-a)-16));
                        }
                        else if((32-a)>=8)
                        {
                            bip[2]+=pow(2,((32-a)-8));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bip[3]+=pow(2,(32-a));
                        }

                        if(bip[3]>255)
                        {
                            bip[2]+=1;
                            bip[3]-=256;
                        }
                        if(bip[2]>255)
                        {
                            bip[1]+=1;
                            bip[2]-=256;
                        }
                        if(bip[1]>255)
                        {
                            bip[0]+=1;
                            bip[1]-=256;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int a=9;a<32;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
                {
                    if(net[b].mask==a)
                    {
                        net[a].ip[0]=bip[0];
                        net[a].ip[1]=bip[1];
                        net[a].ip[2]=bip[2];
                        net[a].ip[3]=bip[3];
                        if((32-a)>=24)
                        {
                            bip[0]+=pow(2,((32-a)-24));
                        }
                        else if((32-a)>=1)
                        {
                            bip[1]+=pow(2,((32-a)-16));
                        }
                        else if((32-a)>=8)
                        {
                            bip[2]+=pow(2,((32-a)-8));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bip[3]+=pow(2,(32-a));
                        }

                        if(bip[3]>255)
                        {
                            bip[2]+=1;
                            bip[3]-=256;
                        }
                        if(bip[2]>255)
                        {
                            bip[1]+=1;
                            bip[2]-=256;
                        }
                        if(bip[1]>255)
                        {
                            bip[0]+=1;
                            bip[1]-=256;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    void prnt(Network net[],int n)
    {
        head();
        for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
            {
                std::cout<<"R"<<b+1<<": "<<net[b].ip[0]<<"."<<net[b].ip[1]<<"."<<net[b].ip[2]<<"."<<net[b].ip[3]<<"/"<<net[b].mask<<std::endl;
            }
    };

    int main()
    {
        int x,y;
        x = cant(x);
        Network* red[x];
        y=((sizeof(red))/(sizeof(red[0])));
        proc1(red[x],y);
        //SetIP(red[x],y);
        //prnt(red[x],y);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Esto es lo que te da el problema: `void proc1(Network net[int n])`. ¿Qué pretendes que reciba la función `proc1`?

Comment: Pretendo que reciba un arreglo de variables tipo Network.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: En ese caso, eferion ya te ha dado la respuesta :)

Answer (score 3):

Hay tres formas de indicar que una función va a recibir un array de elementos:

```
void proc1(Network* net); // La más común
void proc1(Network net[]);
void proc1(Network net[10]); // Array de tamaño fijo

// Añadido gracias a PaperBirdMaster
void proc1(Network (&net)[10]); // Array de tamaño fijo por referencia
void proc1(Network* begin, Network* end); // Por iteradores
```

Si además te encuentras con la necesidad de indicar el tamaño del arreglo tienes que facilitar un segundo parámetro:

```
void proc1(Network* net, int numElems); // La más común
void proc1(Network net[], int numElems);

// En el tercer caso no tiene sentido porque el tamaño del arreglo es conocido
```

En el caso de arrays unidimensionales se podrían considerar que las tres formas son idénticas por lo que no voy a entrar en más detalles. Lo que si queda claro es que la declaración de tu función no es del todo válida.

¿Y por qué hay que hacerlo así? Porque el compilador no puede hacer maravillas.

En tu caso el tamaño del arreglo viene determinado por el usuario y el compilador no puede asumir un tamaño determinado luego no puede construir correctamente el código.

¿Cómo hay que llamar entonces a la función? Así:

```
proc1(red,x);
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Olvidaste las opción de pasar el arreglo por referencia `void proc1(Network (&net)[10])` o mediante *iteradores*: `void proc1(Network *begin, Network *end)` pudiendo ser llamado con `std::begin` y `std::end` al ser un arreglo de tamaño conocido: `proc1(std::begin(a), std::end(a));`

Comment: Cierto... acababa de mirar una incidencia de C y no cambié el chip a C++... aunque también he de decir que no es de las formas más comunes de pasar un array :). Gracias por el aporte

Comment: Bueno, varias de las que has sugerido tampoco son de lo más visto en C++, simplemente lo sugiero por compleción... lo respondería yo pero tu respuesta es más que suficiente y correcta :)

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí. Me compila sin problemas, pero después de ingresar el numero de hosts de R1, el programa se detiene. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: He editado la respuesta para añadir tus cometnarios, @PaperBirdMaster. Lo único que en el caso de `std::begin` y `std::end` habría que remarcar que hay que tener cuidado, pues no funciona con reservas dinámicas de memoria. Esa parte no la incluyo porque la explicación ya se sale completamente del contexto de la pregunta.

Comment: @AndresCaballlero deberás realizar otra pregunta, con tantos detalles como puedas: textos **completos** del error, y a ser posible código fuente con el problema reproducible.